# Difference between generating a readable stream with fs and stream modules?

Tags: node.js, stream

Making a readable stream with the fs module:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/data.txt');
    stream.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(8000);
```

and instantiating it through the stream module:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var rs = new Readable;
rs.push('file.txt');
rs.push('boop\n');
rs.push(null);

rs.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream module allows you to create an in memory stream object that isn't actually tied to a file.  It is meant to be used as a shared interface for providing stream like access.  Typically a module will push data from some source to be consumed as a stream from consumers outside the module.

Creating a stream from the fs module, on the other hand, generates a stream object attached to a file, which means that the fs module uses the file as the source of the streamed data.

Comment: Why would I even want to stream anything that's not a bulky file?

Comment: The streams are used for a variety of things like request/response data in servers, input/output streams for interfaces (the stdin/stdout/stderr streams are great examples of this in node), etc.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html lists a lot of good examples for the different types of streams.

Comment: Is it possible to pipe the readable directly to the response object and output to the client, instead of making a writable?

Comment: In the case of an http server you mean?  Yes, you can usually do something like readable.pipe(writeable).  So you could, for example, take an fs stream you've created and use myFsStream.pipe(process.stdout) to pipe the file contents directly to stdout.  For an http server it would be myFsStream.pipe(res).

Comment: I cannot find quality explanation of what the `readable` event does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77444/discussion-between-travis-and-stevens-haen).

Comment: Ok, you invite me to chat, please. I don't know how to start the room.

Comment: Just click the link in my previous comment.